# Retrieve Passcode from iphone backup files

Tags: backup, password, iphone

This is the scenario in front of me.

An iPhone 4s is available with enter passcode. I have its backup taken from iTunes. I have extracted all the files (*.plist, *.db, *.sqlite, etc.) from those backup files.

Now my job is find the passcode from the backup. I no longer have access to the iPhone.

I have viewed almost all the files and still unknown with the file that contains the passcode.
It would be great help if anyone would point me into the right direction.

If any other security app such as **Applock** is present, where does its passcode resides.

Comment: It doesn't reside in those backups that would pose a security risk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'd make this a comment, but I only just joined the Apple branch of Stack Exchange and lack the 50+ rep to do so.

First and foremost, the keychain database that stores the device's secure information will only be present if a backup is encrypted with a password. If it's not, well, sorry, but you're out of luck.

If it *is* encrypted, then we need to clarify on what exactly you're asking for. I'm not entirely sure if the lock screen password is stored in the keychain file (lazy Google search results: unclear), but if it is, you do have a chance at recovering it, though most solutions cost money. Checkout [this](http://www.securitylearn.net/2012/05/03/decrypting-the-iphone-keychain-from-backups/) blog post as well as [this](http://www.elcomsoft.com/help/en/eppb/keychain_explorer.html) software developer's website to get an idea of what your next step should be.

Comment: Sorry my backup files are not encrypted. But thanks a lot for the link though. This will definitely help me in the future.